# Getting classification probability for new audio files?

Tags: python, audio, keras, classification

I am using a CNN algorithm to make audio classification predictions on a new sample audio dataset. Recently, I changed the code to get the probability of each class (70% Guitar, 25% Violin, etc.)for each audio file but I am getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
e:\Machine Learning\Pro_04_audio_class\predict_draft.py in 
     60                         help='threshold magnitude for np.int16 dtype')
     61     args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()
---> 62     make_prediction(args)
     63 

e:\Machine Learning\Pro_04_audio_class\predict_draft.py in make_prediction(args)
     39         X_batch = np.array(batch, dtype=np.float32)
     40         y_pred = model.predict(X_batch)
---> 41         print('Predicted class: {}'.format(classes[y_pred]))
     42         results.append(y_pred)
     43     #np.save(os.path.join('logs', args.pred_fn), np.array(results))

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

I tried several different solutions but couldn't get past this. Is there any way that I can get class probabilities for new audio files?

The code i am using:

```
def make_prediction(args):

model = load_model(args.model_fn,
    custom_objects={'STFT':STFT,
                    'Magnitude':Magnitude,
                    'ApplyFilterbank':ApplyFilterbank,
                    'MagnitudeToDecibel':MagnitudeToDecibel})
wav_paths = glob('{}/**'.format(args.src_dir), recursive=True)
wav_paths = sorted([x.replace(os.sep, '/') for x in wav_paths if '.wav' in x])
classes = sorted(os.listdir(args.class_src_dir))
labels = [os.path.split(x)[0].split('/')[-1] for x in wav_paths]
le = LabelEncoder()
y_true = le.fit_transform(labels)
results = []

for z, wav_fn in tqdm(enumerate(wav_paths), total=len(wav_paths)):
    rate, wav = downsample_mono(wav_fn, args.sr)
    mask, env = envelope(wav, rate, threshold=args.threshold)
    clean_wav = wav[mask]
    step = int(args.sr*args.dt)
    batch = []

    for i in range(0, clean_wav.shape[0], step):
        sample = clean_wav[i:i+step]
        sample = sample.reshape(-1, 1)
        if sample.shape[0] < step:
            tmp = np.zeros(shape=(step, 1), dtype=np.float32)
            tmp[:sample.shape[0],:] = sample.flatten().reshape(-1, 1)
            sample = tmp
        batch.append(sample)
    X_batch = np.array(batch, dtype=np.float32)
    y_pred = model.predict(X_batch)
    print('Predicted class: {}'.format(classes[y_pred]))
    results.append(y_pred)

#np.save(os.path.join('logs', args.pred_fn), np.array(results))
if name == 'main':

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Audio Classification Training')
parser.add_argument('--model_fn', type=str, default='models/conv2d.h5',
                    help='model file to make predictions')
parser.add_argument('--pred_fn', type=str, default='y_pred',
                    help='fn to write predictions in logs dir')
parser.add_argument('--src_dir', type=str, default='predict',
                    help='directory containing wavfiles to predict')
parser.add_argument('--class_src_dir', type=str, default='clean',
                    help='directory containing wavfiles to predict')                   
parser.add_argument('--dt', type=float, default=1.0,
                    help='time in seconds to sample audio')
parser.add_argument('--sr', type=int, default=16000,
                    help='sample rate of clean audio')
parser.add_argument('--threshold', type=str, default=20,
                    help='threshold magnitude for np.int16 dtype')
args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

make_prediction(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `classes` is a `List`, not a `Numpy array`. So, you cannot use array indexing `( classes[y_pred] )` on it.

Try this:

```
   classes_array = np.array(classes)
   print('Predicted class: {}'.format(classes_array[y_pred]))
```

Or use a `for loop` like this:

```
for i in y_pred:
    print('Predicted class: {}'.format(classes[i]))
```